# Help Sketching graph in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm recently reviewing complex analysis and I have trouble trying to sketch graphs involving $\arg z$. I want to graph the following set:
$$\{z \in \Bbb C : |z|\le \arg z \text{ and } 0\le \arg z\le\pi\}.$$

My approach: $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le \tan^{-1} \left(\frac yx \right) $$ and since $0 \le \tan^{-1}\left(\frac yx \right) \le \pi$, this implies $y \le0$?. This is where I'm stuck. What is next?

Comment: Hint: Polar coordinates.

Comment: so this becomes $r \le tan^{-1}(y/x)$ now what's next?

Comment: Well, what about $r = \theta = \arctan(y/x)$? When $\theta = 0$, the modulus is 0. When $\theta = \pi/2$, $0 \leq r \leq \pi/2$. When $\theta = \pi$, $0 \leq r \leq \pi$. Can you interpolate?

Comment: @snarski so is the answer the upper half plane? I'm not quite getting this I just can't see it

Comment: I'm thinking it's a semicircle in upper half plane @MartianInvader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve $r=\theta$ (see the hints in the comments) in polar coordinates is a spiral:

[image]

You are looking for the domain that is bounded by the curve and the $x$-axis.